# why repmat(1,(1,10)) does not work in matlab?

Tags: matlab

Here is the code.

```
>> a=ones(1,10);
>> b=size(a);
>> repmat(1,b)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

>> repmat(1,(1,10))
 repmat(1,(1,10))
            |
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.
```

Does anyone know why? and why does the error go like that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full equivalent to your example code is `repmat(1,size(ones(1,10)))`. Alternatively you can use a `repmat(1,[1,10])`, for array construction you have to use `[]`, the round brackets `()` are for function call and indexing only.

Answer (score 6):

The expression `size(a)` returns `[1 10]`, not `(1,10)`. So the equivalent is:

```
repmat(1, [1 10]);
```

Here's some helpful documentation:

- [Matrices and Arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html)
- [The `size` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html)
- [The `repmat` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html)

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment. Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 0):

Repmat is used to create an array with n repeating copies of the source array (A).  Hence, the second argument is a single scalar defining the number of copies of A, the first argument.

You can use a vector for the second argument, but it defines how many copies the result has in different dimensions.  Syntax would be: repmat(1,[1 10])

Comment: The second input argument can be a vector.